How to get the sum per row with different sets of columns for each row to be summed with Pandas?
Imagine we have a DataFrame like this one:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[284.77, 234.37, 243.8, 84.36, 0., 0., 0., 55.04, 228.2, 181.97, 0., 0.],
                            [13.78, 0., 38.58, 33.16, 0., 38.04, 74.02, 45.74, 27.2, 9.19, 0., 0.],
                            [88.66, 255.72, 323.19, 7.24, 0., 73.38, 45.73, 0., 0., 77.39, 26.57, 279.34],
                            [0., 0., 34.42, 9.16, 0., 43.4, 42.17, 123.69, 60.5, 25.47, 72.32, 7.29],
                            [320.6, 1445.56, 856.23, 371.21, 0., 244.22, 134.58, 631.59, 561.82, 1172.44, 895.68, 186.28],
                            [0., 0., 32.29, 1000.91, 0., 680., 585.46, 466.6, 0., 493.48, 157.1, 125.31]]),
                  columns=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

df['Lists_to_sum'] = [[1,2,3,4],
[4,6,8,9,10,11],
[2],
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],]





1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
Lists_to_sum




0
284.77
234.37
243.80
84.36
0.00
0.00
0.00
55.04
228.20
181.97
0.00
0.00
[1, 2, 3, 4]


1
13.78
0.00
38.58
33.16
0.00
38.04
74.02
45.74
27.20
9.19
0.00
0.00
[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]


2
88.66
255.72
323.19
7.24
0.00
73.38
45.73
0.00
0.00
77.39
26.57
279.34
[2]


3
0.00
0.00
34.42
9.16
0.00
43.40
42.17
123.69
60.50
25.47
72.32
7.29
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]


4
320.60
1445.56
856.23
371.21
0.00
244.22
134.58
631.59
561.82
1172.44
895.68
186.28
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


5
0.00
0.00
32.29
1000.91
0.00
680.00
585.46
466.60
0.00
493.48
157.10
125.31
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]



Our goal is to add a column with the sum of each row, but there's a catch: we just want to add up the columns that are in the lists of each row, presented in the 'Lists_to_sum' column, that is, each row has a different set of columns to be added
The final DataFrame should look like this:




1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
Lists_to_sum
SUM_per_ROW




0
284.77
234.37
243.80
84.36
0.00
0.00
0.00
55.04
228.20
181.97
0.00
0.00
[1, 2, 3, 4]
847.30


1
13.78
0.00
38.58
33.16
0.00
38.04
74.02
45.74
27.20
9.19
0.00
0.00
[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]
153.33


2
88.66
255.72
323.19
7.24
0.00
73.38
45.73
0.00
0.00
77.39
26.57
279.34
[2]
255.72


3
0.00
0.00
34.42
9.16
0.00
43.40
42.17
123.69
60.50
25.47
72.32
7.29
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
411.13


4
320.60
1445.56
856.23
371.21
0.00
244.22
134.58
631.59
561.82
1172.44
895.68
186.28
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4565.81


5
0.00
0.00
32.29
1000.91
0.00
680.00
585.46
466.60
0.00
493.48
157.10
125.31
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
3541.15



Did I mention there was a catch? There are actually two: we need vectorized performance for the solution.
I tried to solve this problem with a naïve approach, which worked to some extent: it gives me the results I want. But it performs the worst, since the code iterates over each row. For a tiny DataFrame like the one in the example, that's fine, but implementing this solution on a huge DataFrame with tens of millions of rows, well, that's another story.
for n,m,i in zip(df.index, df['Lists_to_sum'], range(0, df.shape[0])):  
    df.at[n,'SUM_per_ROW'] = df[m][i:i+1].sum(axis=1)
    print('{} de {}'.format(i+1, df.shape[0]))

So, I wonder if there's a better way to solve this problem... Can you help me?

Code
make condition by explode and get_dummies(and groupby, any) and boolean masking (and sum)
cond = pd.get_dummies(df['Lists_to_sum'].explode()).groupby(level=0).any()
df['SUM_per_ROW'] = df[cond].sum(axis=1)

df


Excellent, Panda Kim! It worked swell with a dataframe with 1.2 million rows (43 seconds to run). Many thanks!

You can use numpy:
sums = np.zeros(df.shape[0])

for i, indices in enumerate(df["Lists_to_sum"].to_list()):
    sums[i] = df.loc[i, indices].sum()

df["SUM_per_ROW"] = sums

        1        2       3        4    5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12                          Lists_to_sum  SUM_per_ROW
0  284.77   234.37  243.80    84.36  0.0    0.00    0.00   55.04  228.20   181.97    0.00    0.00                          [1, 2, 3, 4]       847.30
1   13.78     0.00   38.58    33.16  0.0   38.04   74.02   45.74   27.20     9.19    0.00    0.00                  [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]       153.33
2   88.66   255.72  323.19     7.24  0.0   73.38   45.73    0.00    0.00    77.39   26.57  279.34                                   [2]       255.72
3    0.00     0.00   34.42     9.16  0.0   43.40   42.17  123.69   60.50    25.47   72.32    7.29         [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]       411.13
4  320.60  1445.56  856.23   371.21  0.0  244.22  134.58  631.59  561.82  1172.44  895.68  186.28           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]      4565.81
5    0.00     0.00   32.29  1000.91  0.0  680.00  585.46  466.60    0.00   493.48  157.10  125.31  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]      3541.15


Or pandas.apply:
df["SUM_per_ROW"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: sum(row[col] for col in row["Lists_to_sum"]), axis=1
)

        1        2       3        4    5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12                          Lists_to_sum  SUM_per_ROW
0  284.77   234.37  243.80    84.36  0.0    0.00    0.00   55.04  228.20   181.97    0.00    0.00                          [1, 2, 3, 4]       847.30
1   13.78     0.00   38.58    33.16  0.0   38.04   74.02   45.74   27.20     9.19    0.00    0.00                  [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]       153.33
2   88.66   255.72  323.19     7.24  0.0   73.38   45.73    0.00    0.00    77.39   26.57  279.34                                   [2]       255.72
3    0.00     0.00   34.42     9.16  0.0   43.40   42.17  123.69   60.50    25.47   72.32    7.29         [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]       411.13
4  320.60  1445.56  856.23   371.21  0.0  244.22  134.58  631.59  561.82  1172.44  895.68  186.28           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]      4565.81
5    0.00     0.00   32.29  1000.91  0.0  680.00  585.46  466.60    0.00   493.48  157.10  125.31  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]      3541.15


